# Firefox detect in php, code not working?

Tags: php

I am using this but it doens't seem to work, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<?php if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Firefox")) > 0 ){ ?>
  <object width="692" height="389">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=VIDEO_ID&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1" />
    <embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="692" height="389"></embed>
</object> <?php } else { ?>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>   </iframe>
<?php } ?>
```

it is not filtering, i get the iframe in firefox and i don't want to as I ony want to have the < object> embed in firefox

Comment: maybe use `stristr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: and why did i get a vote down?

Comment: should also do >= 0 instead of > 0 in case "Firefox" is at start of string

Comment: probably because you said "it doesn't work" no explanation of how it fails, what you have tried or what the inputs are.

Comment: is the $browser variable actually used anywhere in the code? I don't see it used.

Comment: contrary to what @SteveClaridge said, you should test for the inclusion of the string using !== false as suggested in the php.net manual.

Comment: Where does `$agent` come from and what is its value?

Comment: i don't actually use it, i can therefore remove it and i'll do it now in the question. I only basically want to insert the <object> bit if firefox other wise insert the <iframe> nothing else really, but i usually use html conditionals not too familiar with php, thanks

Comment: @Steve Claridge i did write what happens when failing. I did write what I tried since the code provided is what I actually tried. My inputs are what stated above. And it was wrong and it was what i needed help for. So yea, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

strstr is case sensitive, try using stristr instead which is case insensitive and change > 0 to !== false.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

also, can you provide more details on how you're populating $agent? You should populate $agent with $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working:

```
<?php 
  if(strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox")) <= 0 ){ ?>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<?php } else { ?>
    <object width="692" height="389">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=VIDEO_ID&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1" />
<embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="692" height="389"></embed>
    </object> 
<?php } ?>
   <?php else: ?>
   <?php 
         if(strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox")) <= 0 ){ ?>
          <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<?php }
```